# Executing Onload attribute js in the right context

Tags: javascript, html

I'm dealing with the task of overriding document.write (the calls to document.write are from third party js so yes i know its crappy and no one uses it except ads :( )
So in one of the document.write calls the html string contains an iframe with onload attribute set , and because i'm using appendChild instead of document.write when i append the iframe i need to execute the onload js after several modifications that my code does.
i've tried doing something like this:

```
let Eval = function(str){

            return eval(str);
        }.call(node,OnloadJs);
```

I'm calling eval with the node as the context (this) because the js that runs inside the onload have the this set to the current node. anyway i'm getting some problems when the onload event contains:

```
function(){ae.Adrendered(j,Y,0);ae.AdrenderedFinish()}
```

and the error i'm getting is :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

its an anonymous function , any ideas how to deal with it effectively?

Comment: What is that code supposed to do? It's trying to declare a function without an identifier, making it uncallable. Giving it an identifier with `function x(){ ... }` would avoid the syntax error, but it's not clear what to set the identifier to if there's nothing calling it...

Comment: It's invalid code, so deal with it the same way the browser would; don't run it.

Comment: @Jacob Thats not my code as i said it's a third party js that does that and if i'm running the js normally the code executes fine so i need to simulate the onload execution

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can just plop anonymous function expression willy nilly so the interpreter is throwing an error since it's not a named function or a context in which an anonymous function could be used. Easiest solution is to make it a IIFE

```
let Eval = function(str){
            return eval(str);
        }.call(node,`(${OnloadJs})()`);
```

---

Note: The above is a bad idea and not a general solution and adds to technical debt. Specific answer to the OP's situation.

Comment: Great Thanks! I'm still holding the correct "this" in the closure right?

Comment: It should be able to resolve `ae` since it's in the parents scope. You could change the invocation from `(${OnloadJs})()` to `(${OnloadJs}).call(this)` if you really wanted to, but it should be unnecessary

Comment: So i have decided to keep my approach but i'm having another problem, the iframe onload contains something like this "this.contentWindow.postmessage(window,.....) with my approach the "this" is the iframe node which is good but the window object is the window of the main page and not the iframe that contains the second iframe with the onload , any ideas how to pass the correct window with the correct this?